# Validate the expression in Microsoft RulesEngine

Tags: .net-core, rule-engine

I have been using the [Microsoft RulesEngine](https://github.com/microsoft/RulesEngine) nuget package in my .NET Core-based project. I wonder if there is a way to validate the format of the expression before running `RulesEngine.Execute`. According to the README file, the expression is a [lambda expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions). Also, there is a [schema definition](https://github.com/microsoft/RulesEngine/blob/master/schema/workflowRules-schema.json) that can be used to validate the schema of the root object (WorkflowRules) but that wouldn't validate the expressions used under the Rules.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to make sure the expression is valid. In the below code, if an exception occurs, it means the expression has an invalid format:

```
    using System.Linq.Dynamic.Core;
    using System.Linq.Expressions;
    ...
    private bool Evaluate<TParameterType>(TParameterType fact, string rule)
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TParameterType));
        try
        {
            var lambdaExpression = DynamicExpressionParser.ParseLambda(new[] { parameter }, null, rule);
            return (bool) lambdaExpression.Compile().DynamicInvoke(fact);
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```